# Testcafe: Is there a method to check for elements visible within the viewport?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My website has an infinite scroll (lazy loading). I am trying to check if an element is visible to the user, meaning if it is on the viewport.  But I couldn't find a method in testcafe for this purpose.

The `.exists` and `.visible` methods seem to be not bound by viewport.

Is there any special method or function that could be used here?

Update:
I just tried the client function from the linked answer.  I am not sure if am doing it right, especially the selector part. Please help.

```
const isElementInViewport = ClientFunction(() => {
    const getBoundValues = Selector('.grid-x').getBoundingClientRect();
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    return getBoundValues.bottom > 0 && getBoundValues.right > 0 && getBoundValues.left < (windowWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) && getBoundValues.top < (windowHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
});

    test(urlEnv, async t => {
        const elementVisible = await isElementInViewport();
        console.log(elementVisible);
    })
```

Error Log (at line const elementVisible = await isElementInViewport()):

```
1) An error occurred in ClientFunction code:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _exportableLib
```

Comment: thanks @AlexSkorkin.  I have updated my question after trying out the client function now.  Could you help with that error please?  '.grid-x' is the div class in DOM that covers all of the test area in my site.

Comment: The `Selector` constructor cannot be used in a ClientFunction body. You can use `document.querySelector` instead.

Comment: If you want to pass an existing selector to function, you can use the `dependencies` option: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/constructor.html#optionsdependencies

Comment: thank you very much.  This helped me understand more on how that client function actually worked.  But I now realize that it might not help in my scenario.  I will try different approaches though.  If nothing works, I will post it in a new query along with the full code.  thanks again.